# Htaccess wrong rewriterule overriding correct one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been facing this issue for quite a while but I've always simply changed the file names, but I can't do that this time

I have the following two RewriteRules set:

```
RewriteRule ^register-company register-company.php
RewriteRule ^register register.php
```

Same applies for

```
RewriteRule ^register/company register-company.php
RewriteRule ^register register.php
```

No matter what I do, change the order, add flags, escape the hypen, it always redirects to register.php and not register-company, as it should (the link being domain.com/register-company)

The only thing that actually works is completely changing the name, for example to company-register. Do note that if I remove the register register.php line it works just fine and redirects correctly to register-company.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue that your target URI `register-company.php` also matches next rule's pattern i.e. `^register` hence second rule always executes after first rule.

You need to use end anchor in your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^register-company/?$ register-company.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [L,NC]
```

Now 2nd rule won't trigger because `register-company.php` won't match `^register/?$`.

Also `/?$` makes trailing slash optional in both rules.